Trying to download a specifc PDF file from a sequence of webpages
I'm able to login to a webpage. Once in there is a drop-down menu that I want to select an account number from. My Python code is able to find the username and password from an Excel file so I can login fine. The account number is also available from an email, that I'm able to parse. What I need to do is be able to select the right account from the drop-down but I have no clue what I'm looking for or how to access it through Python.
I have minimal knowledge of Python and almost no knowledge of webpages. Anything you can provide that would help would be appreciated.
